# sci-fi series from early or mid 90's

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember a show from early to mid 90's (I think it was 95 when I saw it), there was a girl and a boy visiting some old house. They find a gold medallion of sorts. And one night they see adults (Aliens?) wearing robes carrying gold down through a secret door in the garden.

I believe the show could have been from Australia, but I'm not sure. Only saw one or two episodes.

Comment: Those details are kind of sparse. Anything else you can add might help. How old are the kids? Where do they live? What is the relationship between the kids (friends, siblings, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

*[Under the Mountain](https://www.netflix.com/WiMovie/70124565?trkid=200250783)*

Based off of a book, it was released as a [TV Miniseries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Mountain_(TV_miniseries)) in 1981 and as a movie in 2009.

> The show focuses on twins Rachel and Theo Matheson. While on school summer holidays in Auckland, they are contacted by a man named Mr. Jones, who had met them briefly eight years earlier. This time, Mr. Jones reveals his true identity and mission. He is an alien, sent from another world in a battle against another race of aliens. These latter creatures were a family of slimy, slug-like beasts who could take on human form. Led by the evil Mr. Wilberforce, the slug monsters were now bent on destroying Earth and only the twins' emerging psychic abilities could turn them back. The other major conflict presented by the series is that of Rachel and Theo's emerging abilities. Rachel accepted the truth of their abilities, while Theo was more of a cynic and often challenged Mr. Jones. The psychic abilities in the series increase in effectiveness as the individual grows in trust and acceptance of his or her abilities. In the final episode of the series, the twins are each required to throw a stone and focus their psychic energy into the stone to create a red and blue bridge-like construct that will defeat the Wilberforces. Because Theo's faith in his abilities and his belief in supernatural phenomena in general is lacking, his half of the bridge is insufficient to complete the construct. Mr. Jones uses the last of his life energy to complete the construct and defeat the Wilberforces, and can no longer be with Rachel and Theo as a result. Filming for the farm & bush scenes in the first episode took place near Silverdale, North of Auckland, at Mt. Pleasant, a historic dairy farm & homestead in Pine Valley Road.